# Getting Leaflet.Control.Layer.Tree 'children's' to collapse by default?

Tags: leaflet

I am using the Leaflet layer.control.tree plugin from here : https://github.com/jjimenezshaw/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree

But I can't figure out how to collapse the branch by default. Now it looks like this: [image]

does anybody know how to close the branch by default?

I do not mean the whole layer control that collapses by default I mean the tap where it says '' Warrior ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the branch you want to be initially collapsed, use `collapsed: true` option. This option is inherited from `L.control.layers`.

You can see use of this option in Airports demo of `Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree` plugin: https://jjimenezshaw.github.io/Leaflet.Control.Layers.Tree/examples/airports.html